# Is there a tefilah/segulah requesting that bowel and intestine should work?

Tags: tefilla, choleh-sick, parts-of-the-body, health-safety-shmira, segulah

My brother-in-law is critically ill in ICU and some of his organs have stopped working.

My sister whatsapped me this morning:

"Intestines not working. Abdomen so Swollen. Cannot take in any feeds. Prayer in particular for bowel and intestinal system available?"

Have been searching but cannot find an exact tefilah. The "Asher Yatzar" tefilah is for after the fact, to thank Hashem that it worked, but how do we make a request for the healing and healthy workings of these organs in particular? I am looking for tefilot, segulot and/or kabbalistic secrets, midrashim...anything! We need help, please?

Todah.

Comment: Having extra kavona in asher yotzah with having in mind that the zechus should go to the choilah/cholanis is generally reccomended

Comment: The most straightforward way is to mention yourself in Amida either in Birkas Refuah or in Shmah Koleinu, just the way we mention other sick people, and make Kavonah for the special illness you have OR have in mind that G-d knows your problems, as Moses prayed for Miriam אל נא רפא נא לה without mentioning the deseas.

Comment: There are two books with collections of segulot and refu'ot that the Lubavitcher Rebbe wrote to people over the years or spoke about in public talks. One is called, "Refu'ah Shleimah" which lists by type of malady and the other is called, "Segulot v'Refu'ot", I think. I haven't looked at them in years, but bli neder, I'll dig them out this evening and see if he makes any comments on the subject.

Comment: Tehilim (psalms) can be recited in the merit of the person suffering. See for instance [here](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/1228223/jewish/Psalms-and-Jewish-Prayer-for-Healing.htm) - may Hashem send a refua shlema quickly

Comment: @BerryMink I finally found both of the seforim that I mentioned and unfortunately, there is nothing from the Rebbe specifically addressing segulot for bowels to function properly there. In general, a few ideas seemed relevant. The Rebbe advises to give additional tzedakah and increase in acts of kindness. He says sending a request to the Tzaddik, which includes having a prayer placed at the Ohel of the Rebbe and his father-in-law is beneficial. And the Rebbe also says strict & prompt adherence to the instructions of the attending doctors is essential. He says you must rely on natural blessings

Comment: @BerryMink Here is a link for sending a request for a blessing to be placed at the Ohel of the Rebbe. https://www.ohelchabad.org/templates/articlecco_cdo/aid/3402126/jewish/About-the-Ohel.htm

Comment: Thank you, Yaacov Deane.